# Where do bash completion functions come from?

Tags: bash, debian, autocomplete, raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian (Debian Wheezy). I entered `set` in a terminal and was surprised by the long list. This seems to be almost entirely git functions — ~3700 lines of them.

```
__git_all_commands=
__git_diff_common_options=$'--stat --numstat --shortstat --summary\n\t\t\t--patch-with-stat --name-only 
...
```

My question is, how did they get there and why?

I have occasionally used `git` to get packages.

I have checked all the usual suspects `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `.bashrc`, `.profile`

---

I found a script `/etc/bash_completion.d/git` (I had never heard of bash_completion before). I have to do some more study to work out what this does, and exactly where is is called.

I still need to figure out **WHY** I would want to run this in every login shell when I only use `git` once or twice a year. (The Raspberry Pi is not exactly over endowed with RAM). This doesn't seem to happen on my Mac.

Comment: Also check `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile`, and `~/.bash_profile` if any of the exist and then double check all of them looking for `source foo` or `. foo` since it is likely that the function definitions are in yet another file and that file is being read by one of bash's init files.

Comment: This looks a bit like `/etc/bash/bash.complete` or something similar.

Comment: Bash completion is simply the feature that lets you hit TAB to auto-complete filenames or options in the terminal. This file is specific to Git and lets you type (for instance) `git pu` + the TAB key and have bash automatically fill out `git push` for you. You might find [this article](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/316/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_1) helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These functions are part of the shell's completion support for `git`. They are maintained as part of the Git software. Debian (which Raspbian is based on) distributes the bash completion setup in the `git` package. The functions are located in `/etc/bash_completion.d/git`, in the same directory as other command completion support for bash.

All the files in `/etc/bash_completion.d` are loaded as part of setting up bash's programmable completion, in `/etc/bash_completion`. Debian's default `.bashrc` loads `/etc/bash_completion`, you can edit it out if you don't want any command-specific completion.

If you never use git, remove the `git` package. If you have the `git` package installed, then presumably you do sometimes run the `git` command and thus would want to have good completion for it. “I only use git rarely and I want to save a few kilobytes of RAM” is too fine a distinction even for Debian.

If you want to skip that completion file but use others, you can [divert](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=dpkg-divert) the file to a name that causes it to be skipped by `/etc/bash_completion`. Diverting a file is a way to tell the package manager to apply updates and removals to a file located in a different place.

```
dpkg-divert --add --local --rename --divert /etc/bash_completion.d/git.dpkg-diverted /etc/bash_completion.d/git
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. There are still a lot of functions (not git). I guess what originally worried me was typing `set` (which I have always used to check environment) overflows my ssh buffer. (I know there are other ways)

Comment: @Milliways In bash, you can use `typeset -p +f` to list only variables, not functions.

Answer (score 0):

There are global and per-user scripts that get included at login (`/etc/profile`, `$HOME/.profile`, `$HOME/.bash_profile`, `$HOME/.bash_login`).

On most distros, the contents of some directory (like `/etc/env.d/*` or something similar) usually get included by the global script, where packages can put their own environment setup scripts that get sourced at every login.